# Using Restrict + Filter on ReceivedTime still returns everything in Outlook Inbox

Tags: powershell, outlook, filtering

This code returns everything in the Inbox - how to redo the Filter ?

```
$objOutlook = new-object -comObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $objOutlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$InboxFolder = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6)

$DateYest = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2)
$Filter = "[ReceivedTime] -gt '$DateYest'"
$InboxFolderFiltered = $InboxFolder.Items.Restrict($Filter)
ForEach ($MailItem in $InboxFolderFiltered){
write-host $MailItem.ReceivedTime
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `"-gt"` is not a valid operator , use `">"`.

Secondly, the date/time values must be properly formatted, but your code is relying on the default conversion to string.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict for examples.

Comment: It is not PS - you are passing a *string* to Outlook (which has no idea who is calling it), so you need to play by the Outlook rules.

Comment: As for the date format, see the link above - it has an example using the ReceivedTime in Items.Restrict.

Comment: This is Powershell  -gt  is required.  I've tried all kinds of formatting after explicit string conversion - still no go.

Comment: That did it. For anyone interested in the PS formatting....($DatumYest).ToString("g").  And the performance is far superior to using WHERE-OBJECT.  Thx, Dimitry.

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!